# Format integer to date in eval function in RadGrid Template

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, date, integer, eval

This is my item template

```
<asp:Label ID="lblDF" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DateLong","{0:d}")%>'></asp:Label>
```

How can I **convert DateLong**(which returns int) to **Date format(MM/dd/yyyy)**? I know there is a workaround in codebehind. But is it possible by just using other functions inside the code block?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this...

```
<asp:Label ID="lblDF" runat="server" Text='<%#Convert.ToDateTime( 
Eval("DateLong")).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") %>'></asp:Label>
```

**Edit** As DateLong Is In integer..

```
 <asp:Label ID="lblDF" runat="server" Text='<%#
 DateTime.ParseExact(Eval("DateLong").ToString(), "yyyyMMdd",//Specify the format in which date stored in database
 System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
%>'></asp:Label>
```

**Edit2** DateLong is in formate of difference of days from given default date of db..

```
 <asp:Label ID="lblDF" runat="server" Text='<%#
        Convert.ToDateTime("1890-01-01").AddDays(3652+Convert.ToInt32(Eval("DateLong"))).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
        %>'></asp:Label>
```

Comment: Invalid cast from 'Int32' to 'DateTime'.

Comment: you can eaisly conver int to date in sql can i know what select state me u can use...and if you dont wana change on db than tell what the format it storr i meam 'ddMMyyyy' or anything else

Comment: I know it can be converted to date in sql but I am trying to pass it as integer to make it faster and then convert it when binding at the eval()

Comment: in which format you store date in db yyyymmdd or anything else

Comment: I am still having errors.Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.IFormatProvider'. I changed the Culture to "en-US"

Comment: @HalimbawaDokumento leave as its it will give you your desired output...just specify the formate in which date in stored in database as i metionned in comment

Comment: I am getting CultureInfo is not defined

Comment: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. 

this part I don't know what that occured

Comment: show your one int value that stored in database as example... can ushow me??

Comment: -3652 equivalent to 1890-01-01
or
29257 equivalent to 1980-02-08

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the `d` in the format: `'<%# Eval("DateLong","{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")%>'`

Answer (score 0):

I tried with

```
 Text='<%#Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("DateLong")).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") %>'
```

It was working fine but when it has a null value it throws an error